# pipe multiple commands to less

Tags: bash, pipe, less

How can I do

```
{$several_commands} | less
```

and have `less` considere it as several files and enable navigation using `:n` and `:p`.

That may not be the clearer explanation, so let us consider an example. I currently have a function

```
svndiff () 
{ 
    for a in `svn status | \grep ^M | sed 's/M       //'`;
    do
        svn diff $a | less;
    done
}
```

The purpose obviously is to see with `less` the difference of all my modified files. But with this syntax, I have to use key `Q` to close one "file" and open the next one. I would like to be able to navigate between files with the `less` commands `:n` (next file) and `:p` (previous file). How can I do that ?

Comment: You can’t, since the pipe doesn’t save the output. Would you be ok with temporary files?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I am ok with temporary files, I will most probably accept the answer from ikkachu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use process substitution:

```
less -f <(svn diff this) <(svn diff that)
```

But that's hard to use in a loop. Probably best to just use temporary files:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$(mktemp -d)
outfiles=()
IFS=$'\n'
set -f 
for file in $(svn status | \grep ^M | sed 's/M       //') ; do
    outfile=${file#.}             # remove leading dot (if any)
    outfile=${outfile//\//__}     # replace slashes (if any) with __
    svn diff "$file" > "$dir/$outfile";
    outfiles+=("$dir/$outfile")   # collect the filenames to an array
done
less "${outfiles[@]}"
rm -r "$dir"
```

The above tries to keep the filenames visible in the names of the temp files, with some cleanup for slashes and leading dots. (In case you get paths like `./foo/bar`. I can't remember how `svn` outputs the file names, but anyway...)

The array is there to keep the order, though as @Kusalananda said, we could just do `"$dir"/*` instead, if the order doesn't matter. `set -f` and `IFS=$'\n'` in case someone creates file names with glob characters or white space.

Of course we could simplify the script a bit and create, say numbered temp files instead.

Comment: Since all files are written to `$dir` you could possibly just `less "$dir"/*` and drop the use of `$outfiles` completely.

Comment: @Kusalananda That would mean, though, that you possibly `less` the output out of order, which may or may not be desired.

Comment: @Ned64 Hmm... With the output filename set the way he does it here, it will depend on what "whatever" in the code does.

Comment: It works if I do `outfiles+=("$dir/$outfile")`. I didn't knew about mktemp, interresting command.

Comment: @Tsathoggua, d'OH! Yes, of course the output directory should be there. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to move with `:n` and `:p` there is no other way but to run the commands, output the outputs to files, then `less` them:

```
svndiff () 
{
    d=$(mktemp -d /tmp/svndiffsXXXXX)
    for a in $(svn status | \grep ^M | sed 's/M       //');
    do
        svn diff "$a" > $(mktemp $d/diffXXXXX) 2>&1;
    done
    less "$d"/diff*
    rm -fr "$d"
}
```

(If you need them in order let me know and we can apply numbering.)

Otherwise, you could call a shell executing all of your commands, then pipe the concatenated output to `less`.

Comment: There's no need to override the system's `$TMPDIR` by forcing the the path and name of the temporary directory.

Comment: @Kusalananda, unless they want to give the directory a meaningful name...   On a quick test, the `mktemp` versions from GNU coreutils and e.g. from FreeBSD work differently with regard to `-t`, so something like `mktemp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/svndiffs.XXXXX"` would be needed to use `TMPDIR` and work on both. yngh.

Comment: @Kusalananda The existence of `/tmp` and our right to use it is guaranteed by the [FSH Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s18.html) so no need to make things overly complicated, especially as we clean up after ourselves.

Comment: @Ned64 Perfectly reasonable. I was just thinking on about systems similar to our local cluster where we _definitely_ want people to use `$TMPDIR` for temporary storage. But that's my local situation and possibly not relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU Parallel you could do something like:

```
files=$(svn status | \grep ^M | sed 's/M       //' |
  parallel --files svn diff {})
less $files
rm $files
```